# Is it a bad idea to use a PNG image's filename to store the info on how to process it?

Tags: python, png

I am making a little game app that allows users to load up textures manually. One such example would be a standard deck of 52 cards.

Would it be bad to store the processing info as:

`Card_79x123_53_53.png`

Upon getting the filename from a file dialog, I would split the underscores to get the following info:

- ObjectType : matched to list
- (w,h)
- Number of objects expected (in case there's tailing empty space)
- Extra info (in this case the location of the face-down texture relative to N above)
  and the dimensions of the image provide the rest, of course.

ANY error in processing would of course be raised and the attempt to load textures would be rejected.

Is there a reason why this is a bad idea or should I keep toying with it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, I wouldn't put the dimensions in there though, I would only put info that would otherwise require seeing the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it would be better to ask user about how to process image explicitly either by adding extra controls into file dialog, or by showing another dialog after file dialog is submitted.  In this case information taken from file name could be used as hints to preliminary fill these extra controls with values, but user will have a chance to correct what is wrong and fill what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason why this is a bad idea or should I keep toying with it?

This is essentially like encoding file type by file extension. The only bad thing about encoding file metadata in the filename is it's quite limited in space. You can encode much richer metadata if you used proper PNG metadata field or in a separate file. Encoding metadata in the file name is hard to extend with new fields in new version, with optional fields, etc.

For example, you might find out that you want miscellaneous sprite sheet where each frame has different size, and so you need to encode the position, size, class name, and serial number for each individual frame.

It's fine as long as you don't expect to want to encode many other metadata in the future.